# Problems for which constraint programming is the state-of-the-art approach

Tags: constraint-programming

What are examples of problems for which the state-of-the-art approach is constraint programming? Considering either heuristic or exact approaches.

I'm looking for specific problems, not just a class of problems like "scheduling" problems.

Comment: You can look through some of the charts here: https://www.hexaly.com/blog?categories=benchmark . Note that this source may be biased as it's published by the people trying to sell you a constraint solver.

Comment: Hexaly (previously LocalSolver) is not mainly based on constraint programming as far as I know